# How can I print the elements of an associative array with a for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, associative-array

```
$eventname = array(
        "April" => array("April Fool", 4),
        "May" => array("Labour Day", 1)
    );
```

How can I apply for loop and print the element of the array?

Comment: Please show what you have tried (code; research; pseudo code), we won't write code for you, but we will help you to fix your code.

Comment: http://php.net/foreach

Comment: Who upV'ed this question? It doesn't show any effort.

Comment: Do you want to print all elements in the inner array separately?

Comment: You should be specific regarding the output format also to get better answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date for the event needs to be wrapped in quotes.

```
$eventname = array(
  "April"=>array("April Fool","4"),
  "May"=>array("Labour Day","1")
);

foreach($eventname as $month => $event) {
  Echo($month." ".$event['1']. " is ".$event['0']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I wanted to print value of all element . From your reply now I can . Thanks again .

Comment: @Monzur Completely ignoring the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717421/how-can-i-print-the-elements-of-an-associative-array-with-a-for-loop#comment49492440_30717421 And not showing any effort, shows, that you don't care about the quality and about SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach to loop through the array:

```
foreach($eventname as $event => $id) {
    echo $event;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 foreach ($eventname as $key => $value) {
         echo "Key: $key; <br />"; 
              foreach ($value as $vale)
              echo "Value is : $val <br />";
        }
```